# Надо синонимизировать метки [decompiling] и [декомпиляция]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две такие метки:

- [decompiling](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompiling) (17 вопросов)
- [декомпиляция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (50 вопросов)

Надо бы их синонимизировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово.

```
updating post history, 17 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 17 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 16 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'decompiling': [decompiling] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 66
tag remapping of [декомпиляция] and [decompiling] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym decompiling -> декомпиляция was approved!
```